# SimpleDateFormat change date while converting it to String

Tags: java, android, date

In my app, I am using `SimpleDateFormat` to convert the Date object to a string. But sometime when I change the time zone one by one to test whether the date I enter is the same as the date converted to a string, I found that it shows a different date. For example, suppose I have `Thu Mar 15 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2012` in my Date object, Now when I convert it to a string using SimpleDateFormat it works fine, but when I change the time zone one by one and check whether the date converted to string is same as it stored in Date object then in some cases it shows as `14-Mar-2012` instead of showing `15-Mar-2012`. Why this happen? Can anyone please suggest me how to solve this out?

Code I have used:

```
SimpleDateFormat m_sdFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String selected_date = m_sdFormatter.format(btnSelectedDt.getTime());
```

Comment: date change as per timezone due to different time zone....http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try this ,hope it may help you..

```
private String getDate(long timeStamp) {
  DateFormat objFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
  objFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

  Calendar objCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
  objCalendar.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp * 1000);
  String result = objFormatter.format(objCalendar.getTime());
  objCalendar.clear();
  return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> For example suppose i have Thu Mar 15 00:00:00 GMT+08:00 2012 in my Date object,

You haven't got that (even though that's no doubt what `toString` displays). A `Date` object doesn't contain a time zone. It contains an *instant* in time, which can be interpreted as different dates and times based on the calendar and time zone you use to interpret it. So that's midnight *in once specific time zone* - but the `Date` object itself is just a number of milliseconds since the unix epoch.

It's not clear exactly what you're doing, but you shouldn't be surprised that changing the time zone used in `SimpleDateFormat` will change the date written out. If you can describe in more detail what the larger goal is, we may be able to help you more. Note that if you can use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead, that's a much better date/time API - but I know that it's quite large for use in an Android app.

Answer (score 0):

In your SimpleDateFormat, mention the locale,

```
DateFormat objFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", locale);
```

where locale is of your choice. For eg, I use Locale.ENGLISH as it contains the date format that I require. Otherwise when you change ure locale in the device, the simpledateformat changes to current locale and you end up getting the wrong date.